# Move Data From one google sheet workbook to another

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Move Data from one Google sheet workbook to another. How can I make this work improving the code here:-

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getRange('A5:D');
var destSheet = ss.getUrl('myurl');
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,6);
source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});}
```

Getting this error

> "Cannot find method getUrl(string)"

I can find plenty of solutions one sheet to another inside same workbook, but not separate workbooks.
Don't want `importrange` or `Query` as moved data, must not be linked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is to replace

```
ss.getUrl('myurl')
```

by

```
SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('myurl')
```